# Terminate and nil OmniThread task when form closes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, omnithreadlibrary

This is a sample code for a stopwatch I have implemented as a separate thread with the OmniThread library.

This is my question: Do I have to terminate and nil the task when the form closes or will it be destroyed automatically when the form closes?

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,

  OtlComm, OtlTask, OtlTaskControl, OtlEventMonitor;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OTLMonitor: TOmniEventMonitor;
    btnStartClock: TButton;
    btnStopClock: TButton;
    procedure btnStartClockClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStopClockClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure OTLMonitorTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
    procedure OTLMonitorTaskTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FClockTask: IOmniTaskControl;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ Place a TOmniEventMonitor component on the form,
  name it OTLMonitor,
  implement the OnTaskTerminated event-handler: OTLMonitorTaskTerminated
  and implement the OnTaskmessage event-handler: OTLMonitorTaskMessage }

var
  StopMessage: string;

procedure ShowElapsedSeconds(const ATask: IOmniTask);
var
  ElapsedSeconds: Integer;
begin
  ElapsedSeconds := 0;
  while not ATask.Terminated do
  begin
    // stop after 10 seconds:
    if ElapsedSeconds >= 10 then BREAK;

    Inc(ElapsedSeconds);
    ATask.Comm.Send(ElapsedSeconds);
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OTLMonitorTaskMessage(const task: IOmniTaskControl; const msg: TOmniMessage);
begin
  // show elapsed seconds:
  Self.Caption := IntToStr(msg.MsgID);
end;

procedure TForm1.OTLMonitorTaskTerminated(const task: IOmniTaskControl);
begin
  FClockTask := nil;
  Self.Caption := StopMessage;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClockClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(FClockTask) then // prevent multiple clock-tasks
  begin
    StopMessage := 'Automatically stopped after 10 seconds';
    FClockTask := CreateTask(ShowElapsedSeconds, 'ShowElapsedSeconds').MonitorWith(OTLMonitor).Run;
  end
  else
  begin
    MessageDlg('Clock is already running!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    { Nice: The clock continues to run even while this message dialog is displayed! }
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStopClockClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FClockTask) then
  begin
    StopMessage := 'Stopped by the user';
    FClockTask.Terminate;
    FClockTask := nil;
  end
  else
    MessageDlg('Clock is not running!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(FClockTask) then
  begin
    { Do I need to terminate and nil the clock-task here?
      Or will it be destroyed autmatically when the form closes? }
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `OTLMonitorTaskTerminated` is never referenced. `FClockTask` leaves scope when its owning object is destroyed. Just like any other variable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `OTLMonitorTaskTerminated` is an event handler of the `OTLMonitor` component placed on the form. It is triggered when the task terminates (either automatically after 10 seconds or by the user). I see nothing wrong here. What do you mean with "never referenced"?

Comment: Well, I cannot see the .dfm file. So from what I saw here, that method was never referenced.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have complemented the instruction to implement the OTLMonitorTaskTerminated event handler. For the second point: So I don't have to explicitly terminate the task on FormClose? Thank you!

Comment: Well, depends on `FormClose` does. Does it destroy the form object or not. What close action are you using?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The default action: `caFree`

Comment: OK, in that case, `FClockTask` goes out of scope because the form object is destroyed, and I guess that does what you want right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So this means that the OmniThread task thread is automatically destroyed when its owner form is destroyed? Can a thread be "owned" by a form?

Comment: I don't see any threads here. OTL is meant to insulate you from threads. If the task is running, are you allowed to finalise the task control?

Comment: In Windows Task Manager, I can see that an additional thread is added to the process when I start the clock.

Comment: Yes, but threads are not your concern. What you need to know is whether or not you need to explicitly terminate the task. What do the docs say?

Answer (score 1):

Primož Gabrijelčič, the author of "Parallel Programming with OmniThreadLibrary" writes:

> "We should also handle the possibility of user closing the program by
>   clicking the ‘X’ button while the background scanner is active. We
>   must catch the OnFormCloseQuery event and tell the task to terminate.

```
procedure TfrmBackgroundFileSearchDemo.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject;
var CanClose: boolean);
begin
  if assigned(FScanTask) then
  begin
    FScanTask.Terminate;
    FScanTask := nil;
    CanClose := true;
  end;
end;"
```

This book is for sale at http://leanpub.com/omnithreadlibrary